# Is there any way to recover all files which were removed for pulling a remote repository from github in same local directory?

Tags: git, github, repository, remote-access

I have a local git repository. Some portion of it was pushed in github repository. After that I added some new folders and files in that local directory . These files are .cpp, .exe and .o extension. When I wanted to push all updated new files, it showed to pull the remote repo as local is not same as remote repo. Then I pulled in the same directory. My all .cpp file is gone. Only these files are remaining which were in .gitignore. I had a .gitignore file having *.exe *.o *.txt .

Comment: Sadly, if you did not stash/commit or backup these files in your local file system, then they may be gone.

Comment: I didn't use any such command that would remove these files. I just pulled in the same directory

Comment: Here's the thing: Sometimes local files can be removed _if_ they used to be part of the repo but were then deleted.  In other words, Git thinks it is doing the right thing by removing your local version of the files, to bring it into line with the remote version.